# Why does Perl reuse the same MySQL connection in this Munin script?

Tags: mysql, perl, munin

I have modified the script `mysql_` from Munin, so that the function `do_connect` looks like this:

```
sub db_connect {
    my $dsn =     "$config{dsn};mysql_socket=$config{mysqlsocket};mysql_connect_timeout=5;";

    return DBI->connect($dsn, $config{user}, $config{password}, {
        RaiseError       => 1,
        PrintError       => 0,
        FetchHashKeyName => 'NAME_lc',
    });
}
```

I have configured `plugins-conf` to set different values for the socket reflected in the environment variable `mysqlsocket`. So, each instance has its own value for `env.mysqlsocket`. When I run my instances with

```
$ for i in a b c; do munin-run mysql_${i}_innodb_rows; done
```

then the first one that connects (`a` in this order) opens a connection which is used by the subsequent ones, instead of their sockets. The connection strings are correct, they really change.

The `DBI->connect` is not executed. I can prove this by setting the socket filenames to non-existent files; it reuses the same connection again.

I wonder, since these are independent processes of a symlinked script.

How can I force my Perl script to open a new connection anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Use the manual:

```
$dsn->disconnect;
```

Comment: Thank you for the hint; yes, the original plugin code misses this point, but I have already added it. No success.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/566802)